# ldifde command is failing with "Invalid Parameter: Bad argument '-i'. And also any equivalent PS Cmdlet?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, .net, ad-lds

OS - Windows Server 2008 R2
Localhost: DC as well as running an AD LDS instance

Here are the command(s) I used:

```
ldifde -i -u -f differences.ldf -s localhost:50004 -b myUserAccount MyDomain MyPassword -j . -c "cn=Configuration, dc=X" #configurationNamingContext

ldifde -i -u -f differences.ldf -s localhost:50004  -j C:\Windows\ADAM\logs -c "cn=Configuration, dc=x" #configurationNamingContext
```

All of them failing and saying that '-i' is invalid parameter. But the documentation clearly says "-i" simply turns on import mode.

(please note my local host is DC as well as running a AD LDS instance at 50004 port. And also note that i can connect to the service instance with ASDI EDIT or ldp etc. admin utils)

Not sure what I am missing - I am just following [this Step-by-Step guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732675(v=ws.10).aspx), trying to understand how to sync AD DS users to my account. Not sure why it's too complex :)

Also, are there any PowerShell Cmdlet(s) to do the same - since I am a .NET developer, I can probably get used to the tools if it's cmdlets, I guess.

Any thoughts or help is appreciated :)

---

Please note the following Cmd is working fine:

```
C:\Windows\ADAM>ldifde -i -s localhost:50004 -c CN=Configuration,DC=X #Configura
tionNamingContext -f MS-AdamSchemaW2k3.ldf
Connecting to "localhost:50004"
Logging in as current user using SSPI
Importing directory from file "MS-AdamSchemaW2k3.ldf"
Loading entries.................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
................................................................................
.................................................................
1009 entries modified successfully.

The command has completed successfully

C:\Windows\ADAM>
```

Best Regards!

Comment: Are you running `ldifde` from PowerShell or a classic `cmd.exe` prompt?

Comment: @Jessen, Hi - running the Cmd from class 'cmd' shell as administrator.

Comment: It clearly wouldn't work, but that error makes no sense at all. Please include the error output in its entirety or a screenshot

Comment: why not, am running the Cmd from 'C:\Windows\ADAM' in administrator cmdprompt. please note that following Cmd is working ok - ldifde -i -s localhost:50004 -c CN=Configuration,DC=X #ConfigurationNamingContext -f MS-AdamSchema.ldf (reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jeff/archive/2007/04/01/synchronize-active-directory-to-adam-with-adamsync-step-by-step.aspx )

Comment: Please see the update - i have added the Cmd which is working, but not too sure whats happening, and how it helps me to sync (get AD DS users) to my AD LDS. its un-necessarily too complex. at least to me :)